# How can I align multiple images in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a bunch of pictures of my face that I've taken once a day. I want to make a timelapse out of them. They are all pretty similar, but I want the timelapse to look good so I want to make my face stay in the same exact spot over the course of the video. Is there an easy way to do this in photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using **Photomerge** ! Although it's pretty tough if you are doing it for the first time, you'll soon get hang of it. This PDF explains it in great detail : http://www.photoshopforphotographers.com/pscs3/download/sample-05.pdf
Another brilliant resource that you might wanna take a peek at is: http://www.kirupa.com/motiongraphics/align.htm
I think the PDF will be more than helpful to you. It'll even explain to you the concepts in great detail ! Hope I helped.